# Subdivision surface makes holes in mesh

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I use Subdivision Surface modifier. Some edges I want to leave sharp. As you can see on the screenshot, this action adds holes to the mesh.

[image]

What is wrong here and how to avoid this?

Comment: First thing select all in Edit mode and press M to Merge by Distance, if it does not work please share your file

Comment: Seems no effect. Here is the original file - https://file.io/TCRvgpnIPPIw

Comment: Edge split is the second modifier, before the subdivision...

Comment: @Artem your link doesn't work, please check if lemon is right or share your file again

Comment: @moonboots Sorry, reuploaded - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/KVGG-FFxaXyv-A

Comment: @lemon "Edge split is the second modifier, before the subdivision" - yes

Comment: The holes are created by the Edge Split, why did you want to use an Edge Split exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is normal, you've given an *Edge Split* modifier to your object, by default it cuts the edges according to the desired angle between the faces, here you've enabled the *Sharp Edges* option so it takes only the edges marked as sharp into account. If you cut the edges and give a *Subdivision Surface* to the object it will round the edges and therefore it will show holes. To fix the problem, deactivate the modifier, or explain why you are using it in order to find another solution.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how to make it without using Edge Split? Subdivision Surface ignores edges marked sharp - https://ibb.co/h7Cr05L . As far as I understand, I need to manually make small bevel for needed edges. Any other solution without breaking mesh? _Also please take into account that I use old Blender version 2.79, because more recent versions don't work on my computer._

Comment: How to make what exactly? If you want round or sharp edges, bevel them and choose a width that fits your need?